# How to refactor and enhance existing apps to fit into a dashboard app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written 2 internal projects for the company I work for, with more on the way.
Both applications use forms authentication on a VPN.

I use the ASPNETDB database for both applications, plus user tables for additional user details that use the same username as key fields.

The name of the project is specified in the web.config AspNetSqlMembershipProvider setting as the applicationName.

The boss has asked for a single signon, followed by a menu of applications that that particular user can choose (currently up to two). I think of this as a dashboard application.

So I am now thinking that the APSNETDB should be used for the dashboard only. Once logged it would be possible to check the user tables on the corresponding databases to see if the user can access the associated project.

Now this seems easy, but there are some things I am not clear about.

It looks like I would have to change the data in ASPNETDB so that for each user the application name will be the same and would refer to the new dashboard application.
This will been merging user records where the user has access to both applications.
How do I do that?

And what about links in emails? Currently you can be directed to a specific webpage, and redirected to a login page if you have not logged in. Will this also work if the Login page is in the new application?

I am concerned about the possible need to change live data.

And maybe there are other things to lookout for as well?